# Up to date OpenGL tutorials or books for c++

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm new to OpenGL, I'm on Linux and have an NVIDIA card that supports OpenGL 3.2.

I'd like to learn from the most recent changes of OpenGL. I'm looking for C++ tutorials or books of OpenGL 3.0+.

I know this question has been asked frequently but all the sources seem to be old or the tutorials are in C. I couldn't find a decent tutorial with this criteria so feel free to suggest books too. Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting started with OpenGL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/239917/getting-started-with-opengl)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get a copy of the fifth edition of the [OpenGL Superbible](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321712617). It comes with a C++ library for use with OpenGL, and only covers the modern programmable pipeline.

Answer (score 3):

I like this tutorial, but it's being written, so it only has 4 chapters right now

http://duriansoftware.com/joe/An-intro-to-modern-OpenGL.-Table-of-Contents.html

Comment: That tutorial is in C. I'm looking for C++ tutorials.

Comment: @Tek: What does that matter? OpenGL is a C library. Anything you learn from a C tutorial applies equally to any C++ code you write.

Answer (score 1):

OpenGL Programming Guide, 6ed. It is current as of about 18 months ago.

If you are new to OpenGL, there is not much point in worrying about the latest & greatest features of v3.2... OpenGL builds on it's own concepts from version to version. You need to understand the basics of OpenGL before the very newest bits make any sense. While learning the basics you will find out what new parts are useful to you.

That said the org that manages OpenGL is called Khronos. This page has links to the standards docs and extensions: http://www.khronos.org/opengl/.

But really, learn the basics first: that and a bit of reading on the side will point you at what extensions or new features are worth your time.

[edit] As has been noted by other people in this thread: OpenGL is a C API.

There are C++ wrappers but in my experience they are more trouble than they are worth, they each impose a model of using OpenGL... but OpenGL is really just a collection of C functions and using it as such gives you the most flexibility.

Comment: The Red Book is in its 7th edition, which was published July, 2009. 6th edition came out in August, 2007.