# Create a new open GLWindow and instert a picture

Tags: c++, c, opengl, qglwidget

I would like to create a window using open GL but i can't find any good tutorial, can anybody tell me one?

Once the window will be create, i want to insert a picture on it!

Comment: Well, while your question may be genuine, I doubt that whether SO prefers this kind of _open-ended_ q's.

Comment: I want to perform it in Linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't how openGL works (inserting pictures inside).

To draw a picture you will need to create a quad and then assign a texture to it.

For a tutorial, google Hello Triangle openGL then move from that point forward.

Answer (score -1):

This question is aleready asked several times before. As MichaelCMS mentioned. This is not how OpenGL works. You can do this (creating a window and insert a picture) with Qt too.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10804377/the-best-opengl-tutorial-for-a-beginner-objects-light), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16222231/good-opengl-tutorial) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636406/up-to-date-opengl-tutorials-or-books-for-c).

Creating a window doesn't depend on OpenGL. You can use GLUT or the Qt Libarys to do this platform independent. There exist a lot of tutorials for this.

For a GLUT-tutorial, see [here](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/opengl/glut/), [here](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/glut-tutorial/http://) or here.

For a tutorial for Qt, see [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/gettingstartedqt.html). Qt offers a lot of own classes for a easier use of OpenGL too.